# using category tags in a nav bar on landing page

Tags: tags, umbraco, categories, navbar, umbraco7

I have build a landing page to show case recipes using the product and products document types from Umbraco starter kit.

On the single recipes I put some category tags for the purpose to make them appear in a nav bar on the landing page.

I would like to use some code similar to this

```
     <nav class="nav-bar nav-bar--center nav-bar--air-bottom">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link--black nav-link--active" href="">All</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link--black" href="">Vorspeisen</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link--black" href="">Suppen</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link--black" href="">Eintoepfe</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link--black" href="">Hauptgerichte</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link--black" href="">Deserts</a>
        </nav>
```

I am sure that the above code won't work as it is right now. I have some basic experience with HTML but have no real clue about Razor and how to use the Umbraco Aliases etc.
I know what the above will build a nav bar on my landing page what I want. So that's fine. Only issue I have is that I don't know what to code to use in "" here: `href=""` to fetch the category tags instead of using a URL for a landing page which is not what I want and also not the ID of a property as I do not have an ID for each tag??? Or where may I find an ID of the tags I create on the content like shown on the screenshots below?

How can I fetch the category tags for the nav bar

Would really appreciate some help as I am no developer

Adding some screenshots to show what I am trying to use:
[property on document type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyaQx.png)

[actual category tags examples I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw2UF.png)

As mentioned before, I am no developer so might need to share some more info to get the guidance I need. So if anybody would be willing to help but wants/needs to see some more code please just let me know what to share and I'll be happy to share what might be needed.

Update 16/02/19:

Structure would look like this:

Home
| -landingpage
| -parent landingpage (that's the page I want to use a nav bar that
                                                    filters the childs
|     -child elements 
| -landingpage

[Tree Structure and structure of the landing page in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVl0W.png)

pretty similar to a classic blog page. 
I have used the default products template and product template from the Umbraco starter kit. and altered this a bit to fit my needs.

This works perfectly fine for my purpose.

Comment: Any suggestions on the above?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand much since it's not in English but you should be able to do this in your view:

```
@{
   rootPage = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1);

}

@foreach (var child in rootPage.Children) {
    var categoryTag = child.GetPropertyValue<string>("category");
    <div>@categoryTag</div>
    //do whatever else you want in there with the category tags.

}
```

[Here's the cheat sheet for traversing in Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/templating/mvc/querying)
Make sure you visit the cheat sheet to find different ways of traversing.

`.Children` is for the children (in the tree structure) of your current page.
`.Descendants` is for any node under your current page.
`.Descendants("nodeAliasHere")` is to find any descendant with a specific `DocumentTypeAlias` under your current page.

The idea behind the code should be: 'Go to the root page, get a descendant page, then find the property with value 'category''.

Comment: thanks for that but I guess that is not what I want or need to do here.
The tree should not change as we want to have the children showing all on the same page but at the same time want the possibility to "filter" them by category using a nav bar 
Let me add some screenshots to my question so you might hopefully understand better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please show me the tree too. Will help. Or At least the structure of the tree.

Comment: Tried to update the question with the tree structure And have added a screen shot from my tree. Hope that helps

Comment: @RobF I changed my answer. this should accomodate more what you need.